# Choose user photo without iCloud

Tags: macos, photos, user-account

How do I change my user photo on OSX without iCloud? I can't seem to choose a file from Finder. I don't have enough disk space to use iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which macOS you have so this answer assumes you're using Mojave 10.14.
[Source](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-a-users-picture-mtusr002/mac):

1. On your Mac, choose `Apple menu -> System Preferences -> Users & Groups`.
2. If you want to change another user’s picture, click the lock icon to unlock it, then enter an administrator name and password. You can change your own picture without unlocking Users & Groups preferences.
3. Select the user account on the left, then click the picture on the right.
4. **Instead of clicking the picture, you can drag an image file from the Finder onto the picture.**  If other users are logged in to this Mac now, you can’t select them.
5. Do one of the following:

   - *Use a picture included with macOS*: Click Defaults, then select a picture.
   - *Take your picture using your Mac*: Click Camera; when you’re ready, click Take Photo.
   - *Use a picture from the Photos app*: Click Photos. To see specific photos from a time, place, or album, click a disclosure triangle below photos, then select a group of photos. Select a picture, then click Next.
   - *Use a picture from the Photo Booth app*: Click Photo Booth to see pictures you’ve taken using your Mac and the Photo Booth app. Select a picture, then click Next.
6. Adjust the picture.

   - *Zoom in or out*: Drag the slider left or right.
   - *Move the picture*: Drag the picture around within the circle.